# RegExp Error: Match is not a function

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to compare a regex pattern  into my number input and see if it matches:

```
var number = '490351111313131';

var switchPrefix = new RegExp(/(4903|4905|4911|4936|564182|633110|6333|6759)/);

  var stringToArray = number.split('').map(Number);
  var x = parseInt(stringToArray.slice(0, 6).join(''), 10); => outputs 490351


  console.log(typeof(x), x); => outputs number

  if(x.match(switchPrefix)){
    console.log(true);
  }
```

However for some reason it always return:
**'Match is not a function'**

Any idea how to fix this? or why is it working like that?

Thanks!

Comment: no need to use `new RegExp`, the regexp literal `/.../` will suffice

Comment: please add some use cases and the aned results.

Answer (score 1):

> However for some reason it always return: 'Match is not a function'

`Number` type variable doesn't have `match` method.

`match` is a method of `String` class, so change your code to

```
 if(String(x).match(switchPrefix)){
    console.log(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test),

> The **`test()`** method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns `true` or `false`.

because it returns a boolean value, which is wanted here.

```js
function test(s) {
    return /^(4903|4905|4911|4936|564182|633110|6333|6759)\d*$/.test(s);
}

console.log(test('490351111313131'));
console.log(test('1490351111313131'));
```